# Antiforgery Token in Servicestack Razor Self Host

Tags: c#, servicestack

I have built an app using servicestack razor . I m self-hosting the app with some cshtml views.

I have a template where I want to render AntiForgery token using `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()`;

It gives me an error below:

```
Response Status

Error Code
        ArgumentException
Message
                An HttpContext is required to perform this operation. Check that this operation is being performed during a web request.

Stack Trace

 at ServiceStack.Html.AntiXsrf.AntiForgery.GetHtml()
 at ServiceStack.Html.HtmlHelper.AntiForgeryToken() at ASP.__Login.Execute()
 at ServiceStack.Razor.ViewPage.WriteTo(StreamWriter writer) 
 at ServiceStack.Razor.Managers.RazorPageResolver.ExecuteRazorPageWithLayout(IHttpRequest httpReq, IHttpResponse httpRes, Object model, IRazorView page, Func`1 layout) 
 at ServiceStack.Razor.Managers.RazorPageResolver.ResolveAndExecuteRazorPage(IHttpRequest httpReq, IHttpResponse httpRes, Object model, RazorPage razorPage) 
 at ServiceStack.Razor.Managers.RazorPageResolver.ProcessRequest(IHttpRequest httpReq, IHttpResponse httpRes, String operationName) 
 at ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.AppHostHttpListenerBase.ProcessRequest(HttpListenerContext context) 
 at ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Support.HttpListenerBase.ListenerCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
```

Is there a way , to obtain Antiforgery token on a self-hosted page in  servicestack razor?

Comment: I've got the same issue. by the looks of it servicestack falls back onto system.web, which doesn't work on a selfhost environment. :/

Comment: I moved to  Mvc and Web Api instead of keeping my apps vulnerable.

Comment: With a simple algorithm you can make your own anti forgery tokens. When ill have time I'll post an answer here